# Workflow Look up Multiple Entries from SharePoint List

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath

I have an Infopath form library where one of the fields is a repeating string bound to a Multiple Selection List Box.  The user can select one or more of the items from the list.

That List Box is populated from a separate Sharepoint List.  One of the columns associated with that list is the email address of a user who is the 'owner' for that given item.

I would like to use a Workflow to send an email to all of the users who are 'owners' of all of the items that are selected in the List Box.  This could be just one user, or it could be 10 users, depending on how many List Box items are selected.

I can't imagine that this is a new question, but I cannot find a solution.  I'd be grateful if someone could please point me in the right direction.

Thank you

JR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint workflows can only look up one item, so it will return just the first item it finds that matches your specifications. Options for iterating through items are limited. Working with parent/child relationships OOTB is also a struggle. (I believe there's more capability for iterating through list items in 2013, but I haven't seen it myself.)

[This tutorial](http://blog.rbaconsulting.com/tutorial-how-to-loop-through-multiple-list-items-without-code-using-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow/) does something similar for tasks created by a workflow. I'm not sure whether or not this could be used with an InfoPath library.

Comment: Thanks Erin.  That's a bummer.

I have also tried concatenating the email addresses in a field within the Form Library (from within InfoPath), using the methodology show here:

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7306/104796.aspx

But when I do, the concatenation only occurs if an item is REMOVED from the List Box.

Do you know have any thoughts on what could possibly explain this?

Comment: It's hard for me to know without seeing it. I'm assuming you used a rule?  It sounds like the rule is running when the select items are changed or removed. Have you tried running the rule to do the concatenation when the submit button is hit?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  That worked.  Incidentally, it seems as though this issue only existed in the InfoPath Preview Mode, but once I uploaded the form to a SharePoint server, it was all good.  Thanks for your help! JR